# Can I use multiple annotations on one apex method?

Tags: apex, annotations

Can I use multiple annotations on one method as below? example @ReadOnly @HttpGet @TestVisible and etc

```
@ReadOnly
@HttpGet
global static void doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

    res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('API response');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the outcome?

Comment: Salesforce allowing to save code, I am not sure read-only working or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple annotations on a method or class; they are written as you've done here, separated by any whitepsace. However, some annotations may not work with other annotations, or may not work correctly in certain contexts. These are usually specified in the documentation for that specific annotation. One thing that may be of note to you is in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm):

> ### Versioned Behavior Changes
>
> Prior to API version 49.0, using @ReadOnly on Apex REST methods (@HttpDelete, @HttpGet, @HttpPatch, @HttpPost, or @HttpPut) also required annotating the method with @RemoteAction. In API version 49.0 and later, you can annotate Apex REST methods with just @ReadOnly.

You may need to check your class' API version; this may be causing whatever problem or error you're experiencing.

Comment: my scenario class version is 49.0, thanks for highlighting this